Trying Export .csv with CSV Helper in a blazer server app hosted on Azure
I have installed CSV Helper on my Blazer Server App running on Azure using .NET8. When I run the app in my environment it exports to my desktop. When I publish the app and its running on Azure, The file doesn't expert on the users pc. It seems like it is exporting to the root of Azure app services.
What is the path for any user desktop at any given time? Here is my code?
private async void Export() {  
  if (commModelList.Count > 0) {
      outputFile =  Path.Combine(Environment
     .GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "CommissionTotals.csv");
      using var writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile);
      using var csvOut = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      csvOut.WriteRecords(commModelList);   
  }
  else {
      Error = "There is nothing to export";
  }
}
,,,

I have tried to export the `.csv` when the app is running on Azure app services and the file never downloads. I have put a local variable for the FileOutPath and it comes up c:\\wwwroot, which is on the azure server. I need any user allowed to export to be able to download the `.csv` file.


The "desktop" you're talking about is a server on Azure. This code will run synchronously and write a CSV file on the server. No web application can write directly to a client machine's folder

The server doesn't know the users PC and doesn't have access to its file system. Instead you can let the user download the CSV file from the browser. For this, your endpoint has to return a FileContentResult.
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = await DoSomethingAsync();
    var result = new FileContentResult(bytes, "text/csv")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "fileName.csv"
    };

    return result;
}


Thank you for your replay. Im having a hard time taking the CSVOUT file and converting that into a a bytes array.
